# sum of $-\sum_{d \leq x}\mu(d) g(d) \log(d)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I have seen this sum in "Asymptotic Sieve for  primes"
If $g(d)$ is a multiplicative function, then $-\sum_{d \leq x}{\mu(d)g(d)\log(d)}$  = the infinite product $\prod_{p}(1-g(p))(1-\frac{1}{p})^{-1}$, Can any one one explain  the intermediate step involved

Comment: what is d? what is p?

Comment: AS I just edited $d$ is less or equal to $x$, and divisors. "$p$"  denotes prime

Comment: So the RHS does not depend on x?